# Converting string from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8

Tags: php, string, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am trying to convert a pre imported string from `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF8`. I am trying all the available solution but it seems nothing working.

Example:

```php
$text = "<p>Ayurveda ist die &Atilde;&curren;lteste Lebens- und Gesundheitslehre der Welt. Sie ist in einer Hochkultur auf dem Gebiet des heutigen Indien entstanden und ihre Prinzipien sind universell g&Atilde;&frac14;ltig.
</p>";

echo iconv('ISO-8859-1', "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text); // not working.

echo utf8_encode($text); // not working.
```

Output should be:

```
Ayurveda ist die älteste Lebens- und Gesundheitslehre der Welt. Sie ist in einer Hochkultur auf dem Gebiet des heutigen Indien entstanden und ihre Prinzipien sind universell gültig.
```

Please help.

***Update:***

I am using WordPress with `UTF8` charset. When I changed it to `latin1`, it works fine but I want to covert them into `UTF8`

Comment: why do you expect to see &Atilde;&curren; as ä? If you want to see ä, the code must be something like &auml;

Comment: @AnatoliyR - I have updated the question. Please check the update section. It works fine if I change the charset to UTF8 from WordPress config.

Comment: Your original string have html entities. To convert you need to run `$text = html_entity_decode($text);` and then run `iconv()` and, finally, reconvert running `html_entity_encode($text);`

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes It is not working. It gives `Ayurveda ist die ÃÂ¤lteste Lebens- und Gesundheitslehre der Welt. Sie ist in einer Hochkultur auf dem Gebiet des heutigen Indien entstanden und ihre Prinzipien sind universell gÃÂ¼ltig.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in interactive mode. Seems to be encoded in UTF-8 your text:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $text = "<p>Ayurveda ist die &Atilde;&curren;lteste Lebens- und Gesundheitslehre der Welt. Sie ist in einer Hochkultur auf dem Gebiet des heutigen Indien entstanden und ihre Prinzipien sind universell g&Atilde;&frac14;ltig.
php " </p>";
php > echo utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($text));
<p>Ayurveda ist die ÃÂ¤lteste Lebens- und Gesundheitslehre der Welt. Sie ist in einer Hochkultur auf dem Gebiet des heutigen Indien entstanden und ihre Prinzipien sind universell gÃÂ¼ltig.
</p>
php > echo utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($text));
<p>Ayurveda ist die älteste Lebens- und Gesundheitslehre der Welt. Sie ist in einer Hochkultur auf dem Gebiet des heutigen Indien entstanden und ihre Prinzipien sind universell gültig.
</p>
php >
```

You can try use as above in your environment. If the problem persists when you load your page, you can try `iconv()` to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. What if input is this `ThermosbehÃ¤lter gefÃ¼llt und warm getrunken. dem KÃ¶rper transportieren.auch â&#8364;&#382;Ayurveda-Champagnerâ&#8364;&#339; genannt.` and the output should be `Thermosbehälter gefüllt und warm getrunken. dem Körper transportieren.auch „Ayurveda-Champagner“ genannt.`

Comment: The only thing here missing is handling `„` and `“` characters.